# Generate a list of years with the format of yyyy-mm-dd from yyyy python datetime

Tags: python, date, datetime, numpy

I got a list of years in an array format `1700,1701,1702.... 1970`
And I want to convert it to the first day of the year e.g. `1700-01-01 00:00`

I have tried below code:

```
year=range(1700,1970)
time=datetime.date(year,"%Y").date()
```

but got this error:

```
time=datetime.date(times,"%Y").date()
TypeError: descriptor 'date' requires a 'datetime.datetime' object but received a 'numpy.ndarray'
```

It should be quite easy, can anyone help me? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried simple string formatting? `"%d-01-01 00:00"%year`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could convert the integers to NumPy [`datetime64[Y]`s](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.datetime.html), then use `tolist` to convert to `datetime.datetime` objects (if you really need to):

```
import numpy as np

year = range(1700,1970)
dates = (np.array(year, dtype='datetime64[Y]')-1970).astype('datetime64[s]').tolist()
for date in dates[:5]:
    print(date)
```

prints

```
1700-01-01 00:00:00
1701-01-01 00:00:00
1702-01-01 00:00:00
1703-01-01 00:00:00
1704-01-01 00:00:00
```

---

Since `np.array(year, dtype='datetime64[Y]')` interprets integers as being relative to the Epoch (1970-01-01 UTC), 1970 must be subtracted to arrive at the right date. `astype('datetime64[s]')` is used to convert the `datetime64`s with yearly resolution to `datetime64`s with second resolution. By doing this, `tolist()` creates a list of `datetime.datetime` objects. Without the call to `astype('datetime64[s]')`, calling `tolist` on an array of `datetime64[Y]`s would have returned a list of `datetime.date`s.

---

For some purposes, computation with a NumPy array of `datetime64`s is much faster than equivalent computation with a list of `datetime.datetime`s. So you may wish to use

```
dates = (np.array(year, dtype='datetime64[Y]')-1970).astype('datetime64[s]')
```

and avoid calling `tolist()`.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
years = [str(datetime.datetime(y, 1, 1)) for y in range(1700, 1971)]
```

I don't know where you're getting numpy errors though, looking at the code you posted.